# How do I update the current sts version using the update file downloaded

Tags: eclipse, spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I downloaded the update springsource-tool-suite-3.5.1.RELEASE-e4.4-updatesite.

Now, how do I update the current sts version using the update?  Do I just extract and put it in the same folder?  Is that it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In STS, do the following:

1. go to Help -> Install New Software...
2. on the new window, in the right, click on Add..
3. in the "Add repository" pop-up, click on Archive...
4. Browse to the location where your .zip update site is saved and select the .zip. Click on "Open"
5. give the Repository a name of your choice and click on "OK"
6. After the file is read, a list of components is displayed. Expand and check (for installation) the ones you need/want.

Comment: Thanks. These instructions work for installing from vanilla Eclipse too.

Comment: Official STS Intallation and Upgradation site: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/Installation